# FabricJS Can't Apply Filters To Large Image Due To "Max Texture Size"

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I could do with some help to understand what fabric means by: Max Texture Size: 16,384 - 16,384 what? The image i used is 5MP (2560 x 1920) and trying to apply a filter to the image like this:

```
object.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Sepia());
object.applyFilters();
```

The image object disappears and the message above appears in the console. I can only seem to apply filters to the image if it's < 2MP which isn't ideal at all. I really don't know what it means by a max texture size.

So what does this mean and how can i make it allow the filters on bigger sized images?

Comment: Check [this](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-filters)

Comment: @Durga that's great. It seems if fabric defaults to 2048x2048 and it's detecting my machine as much higher there must be a way to determine that so it can be altered based on the user's machine, thanks for your input there!

Comment: @Durga Problem is if the image is 5MP 16,384 isn't big enough, and from what i read web gl can't go higher than that. Do you have any idea how the texture size is calculated based on the size of the image?

Answer (score 2):

You can set Fabric's alotted textureSize based on the max textureSize detected for a user's machine by running:

```
 if (fabric.isWebglSupported()) {
            fabric.textureSize = fabric.maxTextureSize;
 }
```

Note that running `fabric.isWebglSupported()` seems to be necessary to compute `fabric.maxTextureSize`. Otherwise, it will return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem by using blend color filter of fabric js and i figured out it caused by way i gave photo to canvas ,check it out maybe it works for you too.
(notice: as i tried this filter doesn't worked with svg format ... i used it for png and jpg , code is based on javascript)

```
    fabric.Image.fromURL(require("../../assets/mockup/100.png"), (img) => {
  canvas.add(img);
  img.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
  img.scaleToHeight(canvas.getHeight());
  img.filters.push(filter);
  img.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```